# How does one make Samba change the owner of a file when it is edited?

Tags: samba, file-sharing

I want to add some basic accountability to a Samba share without going all out with the audit logging module. If a file is owned by user1:usergroup and user2 edits it, is it possible for the ownership status to change automatically to user2:usergroup?

Comment: Took me a whole hour to find someone with the same need, all search results are showing the opposite (masking etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samba can't automatically change the ownership of the file for you if it's edited. It would be possible to write a Samba VFS plugin that can do this for you, but at that point you're probably better off setting up the audit module.

Comment: That sucks... I want to use this on my dev servers so that when developers write files, they change ownership and repository auto-commit scripts identify the users accordingly in any revision change etc. Since this is 4 years old, any change since then?

Comment: Sorry, no change in this area that I'm aware of.